# What's a Π proposition?

Tags: logic, infinity

I'm trying to understand Indescribable Cardinals, but the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indescribable_cardinal) requires understanding what a `Πm` proposition is. I've tried Googling all the linked articles (paywalled :-() and I tried using Symbol Hound to search for the symbol, but I can't find what this symbol is defined as.

Comment: The symbol is $\Pi$ ("\Pi"). The uppercase version of Pi-greek : $\pi$.

Comment: See [The arithmetical hierarchy of formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_formulas).

Comment: Look up the Levy hierarchy of formulas. There you can find the definition of $\Pi_n$ and $\Sigma_n$ formulas.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Actually, the relevant hierarchy is the Levy hierarchy; although they're essentially the same, I think it might confuse beginners to be pointed to one rather than the other.

Comment: This is especially true since indescribability isn't just about $\Pi^0_n$ statements, but rather $\Pi^m_n$ (or even $\Pi^\alpha_n$) statements, in the sense of the Levy hierarchy.